# Gradle Karate Project on Android can't find feature tests "Tests Not Received"

Tags: karate

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':browse:testDebugUnitTest'.

> No tests found for given includes: [**/*ExamplesTest*, **/**, **/**/*UsersRunner*, **/**/*SearchRunner*](include rules) examples.ExamplesTest

- Try:

Getting the above error after following all the docs and even getting the project to work in a pure JVM environment, but Android still not working can't find the features

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
        unitTests.all {

                // When running the test task, only run the base Test class which runs all cucumber
                // tests in parallel.
                include '**/*ExamplesTest*'
                include '**/**'
                include '**/**/*UsersRunner*'
                include '**/**/*SearchRunner*'
                // Pull karate options into the runtime
                systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
                // Pull karate options into the JVM
                systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
                // Ensure tests are always run
                outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
                // attach debugger
                if (System.getProperty('debug', 'false') == 'true') {
                    jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9009'
                }
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            // Excluding UIRunner files as these require the javafx libraries
            // which are not shipped with OpenJDK. These UIRunner classes are
            // classes that allow developers to run/debug karate tests via a UI
            // and as such are not required for headless runs on jenkins server
            // but can run happily via IDE of the developer without needed to be
            // compiled by gradle.
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
//            exclude '**/*Runner*.java'
        }
        resources {
            // Using recommended karate project layout where karate feature files
            // and associated javascript resources sit in same /test/java folders
            // as their java counterparts.
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: android !? first time I've heard of this. if you are not on 1.0 I suggest you upgrade because the chances it will work on an "exotic" JVM are more. else you may have to help / contribute